# Contrasting animated text in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation

At 10:56 in the below video, the video mentions a "built-in functionality" that partially darkens previous text in an animation.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iwpi1Lm6dFo

Where is that ability? I looked all over the Animations tab and don't see anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose the animations for different content. I take the following image as an example, I choose "Appear" for these 3 words in 3 text boxes.

[image]

Go to Animations tab > Advanced Animation > Animation Pane > Double-click for each animation > Choose a darker color > OK.

[image]

Then you would see the effect you need.

[image]